# Scrollable Edittext like in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android

In my application I need to have a EditText where the values are numbers. I need to increase the value of EditText by scrolling up and need to decrease the value of EditText by scrolling down.

Example : DatePicker

The date changes by scrolling up and down. I need to have a EditText like in DatePicker.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some deep testing and using, this is a list of usable Picker widget libraries

1. Android Wheel http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/
2. Number Picker from https://github.com/mrn/numberpicker
3. Date Slider (which can be easily adjusted) http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/
4. Horizontal slider widget http://blog.sephiroth.it/2012/01/28/android-wheel-widget/
5. Backport of Android 4.2 NumberPicker https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

When kindly omitted the solution in accepted answer, these widget libraries are very usable if you need alter the design, and you like the way iOS does the wheel slider picker.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will check these links and implement the best solution in my app